# Fields in Lagrangian

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, charge, field-theory

This Lagrangian was mentioned in Schwartz book of quantum field theory:

> Consider the Lagrangian
>   $$L = -\frac{1}{4}(F_{μν})^2− |φ|^2 − ieA_μ(φ^*∂_μφ − φ∂_μφ^*) \tag{3.67}
> $$
>   where $φ$ represents a charged object that radiates the $A$ field.

I'm confused, $\varphi$ represents a charged object, so it doesn't represent a field?

Comment: From a purely semantic point of view, a field is indeed an object.

Comment: In QFT, objects would be charged when they are **complex fields**. Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/417886/